# What does 如 in 如通常在论坛比较普遍的部分网络用语 mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, adverbs

[In the following page](https://zhidao.baidu.com/question/65337840.html):

> “网络用语”，即多在网络上流行的非正式语言，经常引发社会热潮，多为谐音、错别字改成，也有象形字词，以及在论坛上引起流行的经典语录。**如**通常在论坛比较普遍的部分网络用语：

What does 如 in the final sentence mean and how does it work grammar-wise? At first I thought it means "if", but then I fail to detect the main clause. So maybe I'm missing something.

Also, what does the sentence mean? I feel I understand the sentences until the last one, though.

Comment: 如 means like, such as, or short form of 例如, means **for examples**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, 如 can be roughly translated into "like".
However, even as a Chinese, I fail to analyze the sentence grammatically...

The sentence can be roughly (or not-so-roughly) translated into:

"Internet Slang" is the slang language that is popular on the Internet and may often gains popularity over the whole society. They're mostly derived from homophones, misspelled words, pictograms, and popular quotes on Internet forums. Below are some common Internet slangs on forums:
(omitted)

Well...I don't use "like" in my translation in order to convey more precise meaning.

Comment: I see. But then what does the 部分 mean here? I feel 比较普遍的网络用语 is fine and sounds easier to read, but how is it different from the one with 部分?

Comment: omitting 部分 changes the meaning, 
部分网络用语 part of Internet phraseology (slang)

Comment: I'm not omitting 部分. "some" bears this meaning.

Answer (score 1):

Technically speaking, the sentence

> 如通常在论坛比较普遍的部分网络用语

isn't grammatically correct, there is no verb in it. With amendments, "如通常在论坛比较**常见**的部分网络用语" or "如通常在论坛比较普遍**出现**的部分网络用语" would be better.

The character 如 in this sentence should not be considered as "if" but "such as".

"Such as the internet phrases which are commonly used in reddit."

Answer (score 1):

After explaining and reasoning the phrase “网络用语”, the author provided several examples of it that are commonly used on the (online) forums by saying:

"**如**通常在论坛比较普遍的部分网络用语：" - "**Lik** part of the more common and widespread 网络用语 on forums:"

This sentence seems out of the hand of a professional technician rather than a proficient literacy writer, so it is such 生澀難唸.

By the way, another word for **如** is **就像**.

如這些常用語: (examples)... = 就像這些常用語: (examples)...